# How to stop form submit button from refreshing page?

Tags: php, validation, jquery, form-submit

I am using a php self-validating form and I need to stop the submit button from refreshing the page because I need to stay on the index page at all times (i'm using ajax to load content onto the main page).  I've tried the following snippet of code but it overrides the php validation and displays a thank you message even if the form is left empty... Can I just use php to stop the refresh and print a thank you message to screen? my site is at www.vgtesting.co.nf

```
              $(function () {
       $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
             url: 'contact.php',
             data: $('form').serialize(),
                   success: function () {
                 alert('Thank you! your form has been submitted');
                     }
                  });
           e.preventDefault();
          });
                  });

     <?php
  function test_input($data)
  {
     $data = trim($data);
     $data = stripslashes($data);
     $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
     return $data;
  }

// define variables and set to empty values
$firstnameErr = $lastnameErr = $emailErr = $cellphoneErr = $genDerErr = $dognameErr = $BreedErr = $reasonErr = "";
$firstname = $lastname = $email = $cellphone = $genDer = $dogname = $Breed = $reasoNwalk = $reasoNgroom = $reasoNfood  = $reasoNtraining = $freecomments = "";

$formValid = true; // Define a boolean and set to true before validating 

//if conditional statement stops PHP from looking for variable values until the submit button is hit
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
  // check if a first name was provided
   if (empty($_POST["firstname"]))
     {
     $firstnameErr = "A first name is required";
     $formValid = false; // Invalid input - set the flag to false
     }
   else 
     {
     $firstname = test_input($_POST["firstname"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
       if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$firstname))
       {
         $firstnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
         $formValid = false; // Invalid input - set the flag to false
       }
     } 
   //check if a last name was provided
    if (empty($_POST["lastname"]))
     {
    $lastnameErr = "A last name is required";
    $formValid = false; // Invalid input - set the flag to false
   }
   else
     {
     $lastname = test_input($_POST["lastname"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
      if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$lastname))
        {
          $lastnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
          $formValid = false; // Invalid input - set the flag to false
        }
     }
   // check if an email was provided
   if (empty($_POST["email"]))
    {
       $emailErr = "Email is required";
       $formValid = false; // Invalid input - set the flag to false
    }
   else
     {
     $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
     // check if e-mail address syntax is valid
      if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email))
       {
           $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
           $formValid = false; // Invalid input - set the flag to false 
       }
     } 
   if (empty($_POST["cellphone"]))
    {
       $cellphoneErr = "Please provide a phone number";
       $formValid = false; // Invalid input - set the flag to false
    } 
    else
  {
     $cellphone = test_input($_POST["cellphone"]);
     // Regular Expression to allow only valid phone number formats, including numbers, spaces, dashes, extensions
     if (!preg_match("/^(?:(?:\+?1\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?(?:\(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*\)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})(?:\s*(?:#|x\.?|ext\.?|extension)\s*(\d+))?$/",$cellphone))
       {
         $cellphoneErr = "Invalid format";
           $formValid = false; // Invalid input - set the flag to false
       }
     } 

   if (empty($_POST["dogname"]))
    { 
  $dognameErr = "A doggy name is required";
  $formValid = false; // Invalid input - set the flag to false
  } 
    else
  {
     $dogname = test_input($_POST["dogname"]);
     // check if dogname only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$dogname))
       {
         $dognameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
         $formValid = false; // Invalid input - set the flag to false
       }
     } 

   if (empty($_POST["Breed"]))
    {
      $BreedErr = "A breed name is required";
      $formValid = false; // Invalid input - set the flag to false
    } 
    else
  {
     $Breed = test_input($_POST["Breed"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$Breed))
       {
         $BreedErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
         $formValid = false; // Invalid input - set the flag to false
       }
     } 
  if(empty($_POST['genDer'])) 
   {
      $genDerErr= "You forgot to select a Gender!";
      $formValid = false; // Invalid input - set the flag to false
   }
  else
  {
    $genDer=($_POST['genDer']);
    }

  //make sure one of the services requested check-boxes are checked
  $reasoNwalk=test_input($_POST["reasoNwalk"]);
  $reasoNfood=test_input($_POST["reasoNfood"]);
  $reasoNgroom=test_input($_POST["reasoNgroom"]);
  $reasoNtraining=test_input($_POST["reasoNtraining"]);

$require_one_of = array('reasoNwalk','reasoNfood','reasoNgroom', 'reasoNtraining'); //names of posted checkboxes
$one_set=false;
foreach($require_one_of as $key){
   if(isset($_POST[$key])){
      $one_set=true;
      break;
   }
}
if(!$one_set){
   $reasonErr = "You forgot to select a service!"; //error handling
}


   // if comment section is not empty then run test_input function to purge possible malicious code 
  if (empty($_POST["freecomments"]))
     {$freecomments = "";}
   else
     {$freecomments = test_input($_POST["freecomments"]);}
 } 

 // wrap the MySQL logic inside a condition so form is only submitted when validation is met
 if ($formValid)
 { 
   $host="fdb3.biz.nf"; //localhost
   $dbuser="1546259_rsginfo"; //user
   $dbpass="RSGnow12"; //pass
   $dbname="1546259_rsginfo"; //db name

// Create connection
$conn=mysqli_connect($host,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);  

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($conn))
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
//create query
$sql= "INSERT INTO customer (fname, lname, email, phone, comments)VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$cellphone', '$freecomments')";
$sql2= "INSERT INTO DogInfo (DogName, Breed, Gender, walk, groom, food, training )VALUES ('$dogname', '$Breed','$genDer', '$reasoNwalk', '$reasoNgroom', '$reasoNfood', '$reasoNtraining')";

// execute query
mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);

// close connection
mysqli_close($conn); 
  }
?>
```

Comment: PHP is server-side.  It can't affect the client side until the request completes.

Comment: Everything here looks correct, anyway.  Your PHP page must not be returning failure.

Comment: I don't understand, I guess i need to take a step back

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` is stopping the page from reloading when the form is submitted (in this case, it stops the default action of the "submit" event).  The ajax is then sent, and your PHP is returning a response code in the 200 range - [see here for more on HTTP status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).  If a "success" code was returned, JQuery will run the `success` handler, which is what you described happening.  Your PHP has to return an error code, then your Javascript can be updated to use the `error` handler and respond to it.

Comment: i've included my php script: when i enter all fields the form is submitted to mysql, when i enter invalid answers or empty it creates a blank row in sql but in either case the user gets the prompt and will think they were successful.

Comment: thanks for help Izkata! I have alot to learn, I'll read up on everything you've mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For partial submission of your form, you need to call your ajax method on simple button / anchor click. No need to submit form.

Sample HTML part:

```
<input type="button" onClick="callAjax();" />
```

OR

```
<a href="#" onClick="callAjax();">Call AJAX</a>
```

Javascript part:

```
function callAjax(){
$.ajax({
     type: 'post',
     url: 'contact.php',
     data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
            document.getElementById('anyDivId').innerHTML = response;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: its not working...what do you mean by 'partial submission'? I want the form to be submitted (without reloading the page) only after the php validation is fulfilled.

Comment: That is the same. Partial submit means sending form data to server with page reloading.